# How to partition an existing postgresql table according to a set of values

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, database-partitioning

I have two postgresql table as follows

```
partition_sample=# \d+ foo_status;


 Column |         Type          | Collation | Nullable |                Default                 | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id     | integer               |           | not null | nextval('foo_status_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 name   | character varying(10) |           | not null |                                        | extended |              | 
Indexes:
    "foo_status_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "foo_book_old" CONSTRAINT "foo_book_status_id_00f9145b_fk_foo_status_id" FOREIGN KEY (status_id) REFERENCES foo_status(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Access method: heap
```

```
partition_sample=# \d+ foo_book;
                                                       Table "public.foo_book"
  Column   |          Type          | Collation | Nullable |               Default                | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-----------+------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id        | integer                |           | not null | nextval('foo_book_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 title     | character varying(200) |           | not null |                                      | extended |              | 
 status_id | integer                |           |          |                                      | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "foo_book_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "foo_book_status_id_00f9145b" btree (status_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "foo_book_status_id_00f9145b_fk_foo_status_id" FOREIGN KEY (status_id) REFERENCES foo_status(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Access method: heap
```

Data inside

```
partition_sample=#  select * from foo_status;
 id | name 
----+------
  1 | A
  2 | B
  3 | C
(3 rows)
```

```
partition_sample=#  select * from foo_book limit 10;
 id |                title                 | status_id 
----+--------------------------------------+-----------
  1 | a1ed098c-c837-4575-9f4d-66b1e89cdde5 |         3
  2 | ae8bc08f-aa26-490c-8762-8d3d4e801925 |         3
  3 | 0df56d9e-c4e3-4cf5-ab47-1b3ec4a74da1 |         2
  4 | e8a1c8aa-ced8-4a6e-90fc-be78121b6d41 |         1
  5 | 5be057d0-d9ab-4d07-b63b-2be767adee72 |         3
  6 | 067d8827-f184-41c3-9a62-4966244059fc |         1
  7 | 2e7d16d7-17f4-4425-b3ef-1ee1036fece5 |         2
  8 | 7ef45857-d7a3-48a0-aefa-c1dc5e6628ae |         3
  9 | 2e994d61-8a52-4668-844d-559323467281 |         3
 10 | 2d2cc0a3-873d-4090-9778-2e07dc940a09 |         2
(10 rows)
```

I'd like to learn if it is possible partitioning the last table (foo_book) into two tables, one to hold rows whose status_id is 1 and the other for the rest.

I've checked the other similar questions on stackovrflow and dba stackexchange, also looked up postgres doc. but weren't able to find a solution.

Comment: Yes, that would be possible (using list partitioning), but why? What problem are you trying to solve with partitioning?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the second table has more than five million rows, and status_ids other than 1 are rarely needed. reading data from that table is hitting server resources. i actually intended to solve this and after a few research saw that partitioning might do it. am i xy-ing? -))

Comment: For only 5 million rows, you most probably don't need partitioning. A filtered index `create index on ... where status = 1` would probably be enough

Comment: thanks, i'll try it. but let me ask that - what are the limits of that solution? after what number should i think about partitioning?